# svn repository is showing very large size

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

One of my office developer uploaded videos to svn repository.Few days later he removed those videos but svn repository still showing very large sige.How could i decrease svn repository size.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is answered in Apache Subversion FAQ:

["How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?"](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal)

Apache Subversion (and other version control systems) is designed to keep all the history.  Removing files from repo history is commonly considered as a complicated task and not really a good thing. That's not the task which you can easily accomplish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050475/delete-file-with-all-history-from-svn-repository

Answer (score 2):

SVN keeps revisions if you delete them. See http://www.svnforum.org/threads/35631-permanently-delete-file to delete the files permanently.

Comment: @bahrep Citation needed. For those of us that have never visited but might come across it in the future, *why* is svnforum the worst place to ask questions?

Comment: Huh? What does that mean? Does this response answer the question or not? The official SVN FAQ (http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal) also mentions the same steps.

Comment: @Jonners, svnforum is the worst place to ask *general questions about Apache Subversion*. Seems that they discuss their own, ehm, Wandisco Subversion, lol.

Comment: @gammay, You've provided the link to a thread from 2008, that points to SVNBook 1.4 (while the latest one is 1.7). That's confusing.

Comment: @bahrep, Thanks for the clarification. I agree to this point that referring to an older version is misleading. But the actual answer is still valid for the current version.

Comment: @bahrep, there are general Subversion categories on svnforum, as well as WANdisco specific areas. In fact, the general troubleshooting area is by far the busiest.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone browses this topic several years later: a file or directory can be removed from subversion - you make dump, you filter dump, you restore filtered dump. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6025750/1727132