# how to delete a video file from svn entire revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hgsubversion

one of my developer added a video file to svn repository and commited the code.File size is 700MB. later he deleted that file from repository.The problem is I have to take svn backup daily, the repository size is very huge.How delete that specific revision log from the database.

thanks in advance

Comment: The question is covered in Apache Subversion FAQ: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

You can also search the SO site for similar questions.

BTW you've posted exactly the same question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367311/svn-repository-is-showing-very-large-size

Comment: Yep, you are in for a short `svnadmin dump` session. It is not too bad given that this does not happen very often.