# Delete subversion history

Tags: svn

I have a few subversion repos containing bin files (images, dumps of traffic traces, etc.). The problem is that several commits on those file resulted in a quite big repository. Since we are keeping the repo only for historical purposes, would it be possible to reset the history of the repo? I'm basically loloking for a simple alternative to export the content and re-create the repo.

Comment: See http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn repository is showing very large size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367311/svn-repository-is-showing-very-large-size)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/95432/want-to-delete-revisions-from-my-svn-repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way<sup>1</sup> to remove history from a Subversion repository.

The standard way to use Subversion, or any source control system is not to store files that are built from your own *source* files. For example, if I build an executable, I should store the source in Subversion, but not the executable.

Instead, store your built artifacts on a *release server*. This can be as complex as a Maven repository, or just a directory layout on a remote machine where you store this stuff in a way it's easily accessible for any project that requires these built artifacts. It takes a bit of work, but you don't end up with bloated source repositories.

My suggestion is to first restructure your build process to use a release repository of some sort. You don't mention your environment, but if it's Java, look at a Maven repository like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). You don't need to use Maven. If you're using Ant, take a look into [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) which integrates quite nicely with Ant. Or, just use `<wget>` to fetch the artifacts you need.

If you're in the C/C++ world, you can use `ftp`, `scp`, `curl`, `wget`, or `NFS` to fetch and copy the required artifacts from your release repository.

Once you get the release repository setup, do a Subversion dump/filter/load to remove the extraneous binaries, and be thankful you'll never have to do that again.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Well, no **easy** way. However, you've mentioned already that you know the drill, dump, filter, load.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Rob - Delete parts of subversion history](http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/), for example you want to remove everything below version 9000(your repository is at version 10000 now), so you can try this

```
 svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r9000:10000 > svn.dump
 svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
 svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < svn.dump
```

Answer (score 2):

[Subdivision](http://subdi.vision) is a graphical tool that makes it easy to permanently delete files from an svn repository. While it still requires a potentially lengthy dump/filter/load cycle to create the output, it guarantees that the operation completes in one pass and that you will get the expected output, something that is often hard to achieve with svndumpfilter.

Full Disclosure: We are the developers of Subdivision

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is **no** really simple way to completely remove data from a Subversion repository. Apache Subversion is designed to never lose data.

Please see Apache Subversion FAQ: ["How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?"](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).

Apache Subversion (and other version control systems) is designed to keep all the history. Removing files from repo history is commonly considered as a complicated task and not really a good thing. That's not the task which you can easily accomplish.