# I deleted a file from svn repository. but, the storage space size is the same

Tags: eclipse, svn, amazon-web-services, repository, subclipse

I deleted a file from svn repository. It is big size file (about 460MB)

- In eclipse - subclipse(SVN Repository) - select file & click right - delete

but, the storage space size is the same.

I use AWS EC2, and Ubuntu.

How can I recover my storage's capacity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn repository is showing very large size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367311/svn-repository-is-showing-very-large-size)

Answer (score 3):

You are using a version-control system, so when you remove a file via the client, the file still exists in repository history. You can't remove the file using client tools. See the official Apache Subversion FAQ: [How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal)

You can filter the history of the repository to get rid of the file. See [SVNBook | Filtering repository history](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering).