# Copy and Reduce the size of SVn repos

Tags: svn, repository, hgsubversion, subversion-edge

I have one Huge SVN repos which is around 1TB in terms of size. I have two requirement as follows and i would like to know the best approach to be followed to save time and effort.

1. Duplicating the whole repos of 1TB in shorter span of time and create another SVN repos.
2. How to reduce the Repos size drastically without impacting the integrity and version of the files? Here my repos size is 1TB and i want to make it smaller without deleting any files? what are the ways of doing so.....?

Comment: Would you mind further elaborating? It is not exactly clear what you're asking.

Comment: I just did it...Is it ok now?

Comment: There is no way to make it "smaller". What's the purpose of "duplicating" it, for backup, or what?

Comment: You can not reduce size of SVN repo unless you delete something. You can for example delete part of history: http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/, or you can choose some very large files that you do not need so much and delete them completely from repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050475/delete-file-with-all-history-from-svn-repository