# permanently removing files a portion of an svn repository if similar files exist that you want to preserve

Tags: svn

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050475/delete-file-with-all-history-from-svn-repository) and it partially covers what I want to do. I have an svn repository that has 18 top level directories in it. More than one of these directories have binary files stored in them and each of these directories has subdirectories in them. My problem is that I want to remove the binary files from the subdirectories of only one of the top-level directories.

So if I dump the entire repository and then run something like

```
svndumpfilter exclude --pattern '\dirwhereunwantedexesare\*.exe' < dump > output_dump
```

will this remove the .exe files from the subdirectories of `\dirwhereunwantedexesare`?

The exe files take up the most space, however, there are a few .obj files that I would like to remove, too. What would be the proper way to specify a filter that would remove both?

Thanks in advance!