# Using Subversion in Spring Tool Suite: untrack file committed by accident

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, mercurial, spring-tool-suite

Does anyone know how I can untrack a couple of files committed by accident?

I'm looking for the equivalent of the Mercurial `hg forget` command.

I'd especially appreciate any answers that explain how to untrack files using the Spring Tool Suite IDE, i.e. not from command line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not as easy as in Mercurial :) especially if the repo is shared with others and they also need to keep this file (after it is removed from tracking and ignored, the first `svn update` will delete it).

See this answer for detailed instructions: [SVN: Ignoring an already committed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714307/svn-ignoring-an-already-committed-file/714455#714455)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve this by fiddling around. Neither of these is ideal - can anyone improve on this?

**Option 1: Delete in SVN repository, then resolve**

- Navigate to `Window -> Open Perspective -> SVN Repository Exploring`
  to view the repository.
- Right-click on the file and press `Delete...`
- Navigate back to `Spring` perspective
- Right-click on the file and press `Team -> Show Tree Conflicts`
- In `SVN Tree Conflicts` perspective, right-click and press `Resolve...` to explicitly accept the repository deletion
- In `Spring` perspective, right-click on the file and press `Team -> Add to svn:ignore`

**Option 2: Delete locally, then resolve**

- Move file somewhere else on local
- Commit to repository
- Copy file back into tracked project
- Add to `svn:ignore`

Answer (score 0):

Run `svn delete <path> --keep-local` in your working and then `svn commit` the change.

The first command will schedule the delete of the file in repository, however it won't touch it in your working copy making the file unversioned. You can [add the file to ignores](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/props/special/ignore/) afterwards.

- [`svn delete`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/delete/)
- [`--keep-local`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.keep_local)

Comment: I'm not using command line, but this might be helpful for someone else.